# R: create variables up to power of n

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame with `m` variables, how can I get their generated variables up to power of `n`? For example, `df` is a data frame with 2 variables `a` and `b`:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4))
```

I want to add variables up to power of 3, which means adding to `df` these generated columns:

```
a^2, a*b, b^2, a^3, a^2*b, b^2*a, b^3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What happens in case you have 3 columns, would it be `a^2*df[, c("b","c")]` or each column on its own?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Each column on its own, which means adding `a^2, a*b, a*c, b^2, b*c, c^2, a^3, a^2*b, a^2*c, a*b^2, a*b*c, a*c^2, b^3, b^2*c, b*c^2, c^3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `polym`:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4)) 
#  a b
#1 1 3
#2 2 4

res <- do.call(polym, c(df, degree=3, raw=TRUE))
#     1.0 2.0 3.0 0.1 1.1 2.1 0.2 1.2 0.3
#[1,]   1   1   1   3   3   3   9   9  27
#[2,]   2   4   8   4   8  16  16  32  64
#attr(,"degree")
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 3
```

#### Edit:

Here is a possibility to create the desired column names:

```
colnames(res) <-  apply(
  do.call(rbind, 
          strsplit(colnames(res), ".", fixed=TRUE)),
  1,
  function(x) paste(rep(names(df), as.integer(x)), collapse="")
)

#     a aa aaa b ab aab bb abb bbb
#[1,] 1  1   1 3  3   3  9   9  27
#[2,] 2  4   8 4  8  16 16  32  64
#attr(,"degree")
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 3
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. but how to get meaningful column names like `a.a.b` instead of degrees like `2.1`? Is it trivial or it needs another complicate function?